# Failed to start nginx.service: Unit nginx.service not found

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, nginx-config, ubuntu-20.04

I have installing Nginx from source binary with this options:

```sh
/configure --sbin-path=/usr/bin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
    --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-pcre --with-http_ssl_module
```

everything work well,

```sh
$ sudo nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.21.0
built by gcc 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --sbin-path=/usr/bin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-pcre --with-http_ssl_module

$ ps aux | grep nginx
amookhs+    1793  1.0  0.0   8160   736 pts/0    S+   03:58   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

But, when I run the `sudo systemctl reload nginx` command, I get this error:

```sh
Failed to reload nginx.service: Unit nginx.service not found.
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/systemd/

Comment: Hi @Khanna111, thank you. It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved this file as `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server
After=syslog.target network-online.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/nginx -t
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nginx
ExecReload=/usr/bin/nginx -s reload
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Note.** The location of the PIDFile and the NGINX binary may be different depending on how NGINX was compiled.